# Using ffmpeg to restream youtube videos

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, youtube, stream, live

I want to restream 3 youtube videos (each one is a live webcam) in this way: they would run one after the other, but each one runs for only 1 minute. All this in a loop. So my live stream would eventually look like this:
cam1, cam2, cam3, cam1, cam2, cam3, ...
I have tried to used youtube-dl and ffmpeg (these are my preferred command line tools) to download each stream, let it run for 1 minute and restream it. The problem is that I have to start ffmpeg each time. So when it stops and starts again, the live stream stops and starts again (after about 15 seconds). Here is my code (for bash):

The main script: (FILE is an array with the 3 URLs for the videos)

```
for URL in "${FILE[@]}"
do
  timeout 1m /usr/local/bin/get_livestream.sh $URL
done
```

and get_livestream.sh:

```
youtube-dl -q -o - -- $1 | ffmpeg -re -loglevel warning -hide_banner \
  -i - -s 960x540 -c:v libx264 -b:v 2M -c:a copy \
  -strict -2 -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -bufsize 2100k \
  -f flv rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/<key>
```

Comment: Can you save the youtube-dl to 3 files, edit them as needed or one minute, then call fmgepg. Better yet, edit the 3 1 min files into one file (just one time) with ffmpeg. There may be a feature that keeps ffmpeg "running" non-stop, but you'd have to read the help for `ffmpeg` carefully to igure out how to do that. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for trying to solve this. The point is that these are live videos, so if I record and concatenate them, then restream, the stream is no longer live. Also, I will have to be able to scale from 3 videos to hundreds.

Comment: Hmm, that wasn't clear from you inistial posting. Maybe you can clarify your use case a little futher, as I'm still not sure what you're trying to accomplish, especially when you say "ale from 3 videos to hundreds." (what sort of viewing experience will that be?) . Upvoted your Q as you've included an attempt to solve/illustrate your problem. Also, I think you'll find that such hackery (as I describe) is what even big-name tools are doing in the background. Good luck!

Comment: I get the "cam1, cam2, cam3, cam1, cam2, cam3, ... " thing, but that seems static, and that you should be able to save what you want as a file, and then stitch it together with `ffmpeg`. OK, out of ideas! ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for answering again. And thanks for the upvote! :-) I am in a test phase, so I try with only three videos for now. The idea behind it is to download some webcam videos (that are being live streamed) and show them on my LAN at home. So the useres here would see each live webcam for 1 minute, then the next and so on. Since each webcam video is a live stream, it doesn't make sense to fist download, then use the ffmpeg concat and then restream, since it will take some time and users in the LAN will not see live image anymore. A few secs later is OK, but not 10 minutes or more. Makes sense?

Comment: Look into using the overlay filter with the `enable` option using an expression. Probably a few similar examples on this site. Just have to search.

Comment: Hm, I don't understand how that could help. The problem is that I have to restart ffmpeg for each video and therefore the stream stops  each time. (The stream only continues after a 15 second delay.) The goal is a smooth experience.

Comment: @ILoveCake hey were you able to solve this?